# How and where to get PCI DSS certification for Amazon EC2 for my Android application

Tags: android, node.js, amazon-ec2, pci-compliance, pci-dss

I have a `cordova` based `hybrid android mobile application` for which i am using `NodeJS` as server which is installed in `Amazon EC2 cloud instance`.

My Application is an online ordering system, for which i have to accept payments.

But for accepting payments my server has to be `PCI DSS` compliant.

But i didn't found any link which explains the process of getting the `PCI DSS` certification in India.

Please help me if anyone has done the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're taking card data yourself, rather than handing it off to an established payment gateway, you're going to want to contact a QSA that does business in India.

[Here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/assessors_and_solutions/qualified_security_assessors) is the official list of all certified QSAs - just search for India and the region you intend on servicing.